# Replace <a> with React <Link> in text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

in my React app I am getting some HTML from another server (Wikipedia) and - in this text - want to replace all the  links with react-router  links.

What I have come up with is the following code:

```
// Parse HTML with JavaScript DOM Parser
let parser = new DOMParser();
let el = parser.parseFromString('<div>' + html + '</div>', 'text/html');

// Replace links with react-router links
el.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  let to = a.getAttribute('href');
  let text = a.innerText;
  let link = <Link to={to}>{text}</Link>;
  a.replaceWith(link);
});
this.setState({
  html: el.innerHTML
})
```

Then later in `render()` I then inserted it into the page using

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.html}} />
```

The problem is that React JSX is not a native JavaScript element thus not working with `replaceWith`. I also assume that such a `Link` object can not be stored as text and then later be restored using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

So: what is the best way to do this method? I want to keep all the various elements around the link so I cannot simply loop through the  links in `render()`

Comment: You can make links that utilize the history API in order to "programatically" influence the react-router, the same way when you would want any part of the javascript to change a page without using a `<link>`

Answer (score 4):

Umm, you really need to use `Link`
Option 1:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
el.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  let to = a.getAttribute('href');
  let text = a.innerText;
  const link = renderToString(<Link to={to}>{text}</Link>);
  a.replaceWith(link);
});
```

Option 2: Use `html-react-parser`

Comment: smart move. way better than parsing

Comment: Does that actually work? Since renderToString is designed to be used on the server, presumably the relevant onClick handlers etc. won't be correctly setup for the `Link` component when using this

Answer (score 3):

You can not render `<Link>` like this.
Instead you could try another way:

```
el.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a) => {
    a.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
       event.preventDefault()
       const href = a.getAttribute('href');
       // use React Router to link manually to href
    })
})
```

when click on `<a>` you routing manually.

See [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage functionality of [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)

```
import parse, { domToReact } from 'html-react-parser';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';    

function parseWithLinks(text) {
  const options = {
    replace: ({ name, attribs, children }) => {
      if (name === 'a' && attribs.href) {
        return <Link to={attribs.href}>{domToReact(children)}</Link>;
      }
    }
  };
      
  return parse(text, options);
}
```

And then use it like:

```
const textWithRouterLinks = parseWithLinks('<a href="/home">Home page</a>');
```